# Подгрузка контента через XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

При нажатии на кнопку хочу подгрузить контент. Только не знаю, в каком виде php-скрипт должен возвратить ответ. 
JS:

```
function load() {
        xhr.open('POST', './script.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var elems = xhr.responseText;
                document.querySelector(".content").appendChild(elems);

            }
        }
        xhr.send("load=true$from="+fact_id+"&to="+fact_id+1);
    }
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['load'])) {
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM puzzles LIMIT $from, $to ");

    while(($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))!=false){
    echo '<div>';
    echo $row['description'];
    echo '</div>';

}
```

При таком коде будет ошибка: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`.
Какие данные мне возвращать в ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не на стороне php, а в js коде. 
Метод `appendChild` ожидает `Node`, а получает строку, нужно не много изменить код, на вот такой:

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var response = document.createElement('div');
    response.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    document.querySelector(".content").appendChild(response);
}
```